# using bcp to load data errors on datetime

Tags: sql-server, bcp

I am running this bcp command:

```
/opt/mssql-tools/bin/bcp buyerhero_staging.dbo.mytable IN "/home/airflow/airflow/staging/site/Leads.txt" -F2  -U<<username>> -P<<password>> -S<<Server>> -t"|" -c  -r"0x0A" -e error.txt
```

The last column of this data is the same datetime value.

example data:

```
870950956|165452666|2020-05-07|Internet|ST|LOCATION|Description||9152768067|(Do Not Call Registry)|Robert Garcia||||||||||||1000|3|1|0.14|1959|Carport, 1 space|84800|915|276|||||||Address||Town|ST|79924|2020-05-15 15:11:16
870951459||2020-05-07|Internet|ST|LOCATION|Description||2672418667|(Do Not Call Registry)||||||||||||||||0.55|||6500|267|241|||||||Address||town|ST|32428|2020-05-15 15:11:16
870951519|169648811|2020-05-07|Internet|ST|LOCATION|Description||3153910470||||||||||||||1973|3|2|0.42|1962|Attached Garage, 2 spaces|195000|315|391|||||||Address||TOwn|ST|13212|2020-05-15 15:11:16
```

The last column is a date time `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` and it's the same value.

However I am getting random errors about date format:

```
1000 rows sent to SQL Server. Total sent: 1000
1000 rows sent to SQL Server. Total sent: 2000
1000 rows sent to SQL Server. Total sent: 3000
SQLState = 22008, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Invalid date format
1000 rows sent to SQL Server. Total sent: 4000
1000 rows sent to SQL Server. Total sent: 5000
1000 rows sent to SQL Server. Total sent: 6000
SQLState = 22008, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Invalid date format
1000 rows sent to SQL Server. Total sent: 7000
1000 rows sent to SQL Server. Total sent: 8000
1000 rows sent to SQL Server. Total sent: 9000
1000 rows sent to SQL Server. Total sent: 10000
1000 rows sent to SQL Server. Total sent: 11000
SQLState = 22008, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Invalid date format
```

how do I fix the data format issue?  if I modify the column to varchar, it works fine, but I need datetime.

Thank you

## Update 1

I was told to use a Format File.
here is the format:

```
14.0
43
1       SQLCHAR             2       500     "|"   1     Lead_ID                                                                      SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
2       SQLBIGINT           1       8       "|"   2     Attom_ID                                                                     ""
3       SQLCHAR             2       500     "|"   3     Date                                                                         SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
4       SQLCHAR             2       500     "|"   4     Data_Source                                                                  SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
5       SQLCHAR             2       500     "|"   5     Area_ST                                                                      SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
6       SQLCHAR             2       500     "|"   6     Area_Name                                                                    SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
7       SQLCHAR             8       0       "|"   7     Description_Ad                                                               SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
8       SQLCHAR             2       5000    "|"   8     Contact_Email                                                                SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
9       SQLCHAR             2       5000    "|"   9     Contact_Phone1                                                               SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
10      SQLCHAR             2       5000    "|"   10    Phone1_DNC                                                                   SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
11      SQLCHAR             2       500     "|"   11    Contact_Name1                                                                SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
12      SQLCHAR             2       5000    "|"   12    Contact_Street1                                                              SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
13      SQLCHAR             2       500     "|"   13    Contact_City1                                                                SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
14      SQLCHAR             2       5000    "|"   14    Contact_ST1                                                                  SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
15      SQLCHAR             2       500     "|"   15    Contact_ZIP1                                                                 SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
16      SQLCHAR             2       500     "|"   16    Contact_Phone2                                                               SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
17      SQLCHAR             2       500     "|"   17    Phone2_DNC                                                                   SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
18      SQLCHAR             2       500     "|"   18    Contact_Name2                                                                SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
19      SQLCHAR             2       500     "|"   19    Contact_Street2                                                              SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
20      SQLCHAR             2       500     "|"   20    Contact_City2                                                                SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
21      SQLCHAR             2       500     "|"   21    Contact_ST2                                                                  SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
22      SQLCHAR             2       500     "|"   22    Contact_ZIP2                                                                 SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
23      SQLCHAR             2       500     "|"   23    Square_Feet                                                                  SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
24      SQLCHAR             2       500     "|"   24    Bedrooms                                                                     SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
25      SQLCHAR             2       500     "|"   25    Bathrooms                                                                    SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
26      SQLCHAR             2       500     "|"   26    Lot_Size                                                                     SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
27      SQLCHAR             2       500     "|"   27    Year_Built                                                                   SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
28      SQLCHAR             2       500     "|"   28    Garage                                                                       SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
29      SQLCHAR             2       500     "|"   29    Price                                                                        SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
30      SQLCHAR             2       500     "|"   30    Phone1_PF_AreaCode                                                           SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
31      SQLCHAR             2       500     "|"   31    Phone1_PF_Prefix                                                             SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
32      SQLCHAR             2       500     "|"   32    Phone1_PF_City                                                               SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
33      SQLCHAR             2       500     "|"   33    Phone1_PF_ST                                                                 SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
34      SQLCHAR             2       500     "|"   34    Phone2_PF_AreaCode                                                           SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
35      SQLCHAR             2       500     "|"   35    Phone2_PF_Prefix                                                             SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
36      SQLCHAR             2       500     "|"   36    Phone2_PF_City                                                               SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
37      SQLCHAR             2       500     "|"   37    Phone2_PF_ST                                                                 SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
38      SQLCHAR             2       500     "|"   38    Property_Street                                                              SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
39      SQLCHAR             2       500     "|"   39    Property_Street_2                                                            SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
40      SQLCHAR             2       500     "|"   40    Property_City                                                                SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
41      SQLCHAR             2       500     "|"   41    Property_ST                                                                  SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
42      SQLCHAR             2       500     "|"   42    Property_ZIP                                                                 SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
43      SQLDATETIME         1       8       "0x0a"   43    LOADDATE                                                                     ""
```

column 43 is the column I am having issues.
The file is unix lined utf-8.
the response I get is:

```
Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Unexpected EOF encountered in BCP data-file
```

how do I fix this?
Thanks

Comment: I would suggest creating the format file and then try. mostly, this kind of error is date-time setting on your machine check the date format for a quick fix.

Comment: I updated my question.  i'm getting a EOF failure.

Comment: If there's any risk of bad data in the source file, you should import data into varchar columns, then convert them internally in SQL server. That way at least you can inspect the imported data and try and fix (or write it to an error table)

Comment: Your BCP command does not use the option to specify a format file. You have created a format file, but you are not using it. Using a format file (using the -f option) negates or overrides the -c, -r and -t options. You should either be using -c, -r and -t or using a format file. cannot do both.

Comment: I decided to work with Nick's solution.  Since it's a staging table, I have the ability to re-transform it afterwards.  Thanks~

Answer (score 0):

Your format file doesn't look quite right. You should be able to generate it using BCP itself, e.g.:

```sh
bcp buyerhero_staging.dbo.mytable format nul -S <Server> -U <Username> -P <Password> -c -f mytable.fmt -t"|" -r"\n"
```

BCP often ignores the `-r` switch (record delimiter) and writes `"\r\n"` in the format file regardless, so you'll need to check this and replace it with just `"\n"` if it did that. You should then be able to import your Leads.txt file with:

```sh
bcp buyerhero_staging.dbo.mytable IN Leads.txt -f MyTable.fmt -S <Server> -U <Username> -P <Password> -e error.txt
```